# python: import, modify, and save external module

Tags: python

I want to have a python module stored in a variable location that I can import and modify.  For example, I may want the module to contain a list of names:

/path/to/module/names.py:

```
names=['Bill', 'Tom', 'Mary', 'Lisa', 'Steve']
```

and in my app I may want to import this list, add a name, and then store it again.  I know I can import using the `imp` module, as below:

```
f, p, t = imp.find_module('names', ['/path/to/module']) 
names_mod = imp.load_module('names', f, p, t)
names = names_mod.names
```

Now `names` contains the list `['Bill', 'Tom', 'Mary', 'Lisa', 'Steve']`.  My question is if I want to add `'Ann'` to the list (`names.append('Ann')`), how can I do that and save it back into the `names` module, so that the next time I import the module, the list will contain `'Ann'` as well?

I know this could be done by directly writing to the file and overwriting the list with `f.write()`, but if the module is large and I only want to change that one element, is there a way to do it?

Comment: Not sure you should be keeping anything that isn't *constant* inside the module. That's what databases are for.

Comment: @JCOC611 agreed, but this entire app is a mess and I have to work with what I've got.

Comment: Second this. You don't want to alter the module programmatically to do things like that. Write the list to some form of storage: a database, a file, etc. Take a look an `json` module and `ConfigParser` module; they give easy ways to load and store structured data like lists. If you need to alter a module, use a text editor. Don't yield to bad practices, even when pragmatism requires to tolerate them in the legacy code.

Comment: The answer to messy code is never *more* messy code...

Comment: @9000 ok, so I'm trying to work with `json`. there must be a straightforward way to load the data, modify it, and write it back to the file, but I can't seem to find one.  [here's my problem](http://pastebin.com/ZsCVMj0f)

Comment: @ewok: there is. [This example](http://pastebin.com/ZaMVw9pL) should give you an idea. It assumes Linux/OSX command line to create the example file, but the Python part will work on any platform.